# Cypress - contains and exist vs should and have

Tags: cypress

I was testing for text inside a `div`. When I wrote `cy.get('[testid=t]').contains('text').should('exist')` it failed but writing `cy.get('[testid=t]'.should('have.text', 'text')` passes. What is the difference between these two implementations?

Answer (score 0):

The first approach, the [`.contains()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains) is a child command meaning it will search within the previous subject for an element matching the arguments given to the the `.contains()`. `.contains()` is a dual command and can either be a parent or child command.

```js
cy.contains('.selector')
cy.get('.selector').contains('.child-selector')
```

For your first approach to work, the html would need to look something like this.

```html
<div testid="t"> 
  <div>
    text
  </div>
</div>
```

You can rewrite the first approach with just using `.contains()`. `.should('exist')` is an [default assertion](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-Cypress#Default-Assertions) for `.get()` and `.contains()`
Example HTML

```html
<div testid="t"> 
  text
</div>
```

```js
cy.contains('[testid=t]', 'text').should('be.visible')
```

The second approach, is straight forward and makes an assertion on the matching element.